Django DRF_Spectacular and dynamic serializer problem
i have a 2 serializers
when i get the list of ItemCategory i want have all fields so ItemCategorySerializer is enough but when i call ItemCategorySerializer from ItemSerializer i want print only id and name but when i generate the swagger schema inside my schema list i find ItemCategory with only 'id', 'name'
class ItemCategorySerializer(coreSerializers.DynamicModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemCategory
        fields = "__all__"

class ItemSerializer(coreSerializers.DynamicModelSerializer,):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = "__all__"

    category_obj = ItemCategorySerializer(source='category', many=False, read_only=True, required=False, allow_null=True, partial=True, fields=['id', 'name', ])

so, i have this inside swagger this schema

but i want that

i think that happen because before it generate ItemCategory full
then ItemSerializer call ItemCategorySerializer and replace ItemCategory full with minimized:
how i can force to use in schema model ItemCategory full  ?
